# Angularfire; how to add new data into existing firebase list object

Tags: facebook, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose i have Firebase there is list of object called firebaseList having an object KF6dlZnUlilVtNykDEN with one property title : "value" and i want to add an array in this existing KF6dlZnUlilVtNykDEN how can i do that?

Actually i want to build Facebook like firebase, post and their comment suppose if title is post so how to structure for comment data

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: Instead of describing your code and data structure, post a snippet of the actual code and JSON (as text please, no screenshots). That way we can see what you've done and the data you're working with. This will make is a lot easier to help you.